# PHP Class Function to Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a PHP function in a class (that uses cURL) I use to gather JSON data but I manually call the function. The JSN data is then added (one line at a time...) to a table. I would like to automate this functionality to run once a week. I know that MySQL UDF's are highly discouraged but are stored procedures, event procedures, triggers, etc. completely NOT an option? What are GOOD options?

Comment: why not use CRON JOB?

Comment: Are there pros and cons to using cron jobs over an event procedure in MySQL or SQL Server? I would prefer to avoid injecting code at the database level. Plus I am not aware of what negative(s) come with use of cron jobs.